# what actually model.save() saves in Keras?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have a Keras model and i trained the model with 100 epochs.

now, i got 0.0085 loss at epoch 85 and at lat epoch i got 0.0092.

My question is,

1. what does model.save() in Keras saves?
2. Is it save the weights it got from lat epoch(i.e., 100)
3. Or is it saves the weights from best epoch (i,e., epoch 85)
4. Or average or mean weights from all 100 epochs?.

What actually keras model.save() is designed to save the weights after 100 epochs completion?.

Thanks for Explanation in Advance:).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It saves weights
2. Yes
3. For saving weights for best epoch, use chunk of code i have given below
4. No

What actually keras model.save() is designed to save the weights after 100 epochs completion?. Yes it does, but have a look at following code for saving weights of only best epochs.

Use this chunk of code to:

1. Save weights of best epochs only
2. Update weights after every epoch only if given criteria is improved (val_loss is min)
3. Additionally, history after each epoch will be save in .csv file.

## Code

```
import pandas as pd
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ModelCheckpoint

#Stop when val_loss is not decreasing
earlyStopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, verbose=0, mode='min')

#Save the model after every epoch.
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='Model_1_weights.h5', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

#history variable will save training progress after each epoch 
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=20, epochs=40, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid), shuffle=True, callbacks=[checkpointer, earlyStopping])
#Save progress of each epoch in .csv file 
hist_df = pd.DataFrame(history.history) 
hist_csv_file = 'History_Model_1.csv'
with open(hist_csv_file, mode='w') as f:
    hist_df.to_csv(f)
```

Link: https://keras.io/callbacks/#ModelCheckpoint

Comment: In EarlyStopping patience=10. What is it mean?. Is that means for example let from 20 onwards model is not decreasing loss till 30 the. Weights of epoch 30 is saved or epoch 20 is saved.

Answer (score 2):

The `model.save()` saves the whole architecture, weights and the optimizer state. This command saves the details needed to reconstitute your model.

The command will save:

- The architecture of the model, allowing to re-create the model;
- The weights of the model;
- The training configuration (loss, optimizer);
- the state of the optimizer, allowing to resume training exactly where you left off.

So you can reuse your model using `keras.models.load_model(filepath)` to reinstantiate your model. `load_model` will also take care of compiling the model using the saved training configuration.

See the example:

```py
from keras.models import load_model

model.save('my_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
del model  # deletes the existing model

# returns a compiled model
# identical to the previous one
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

Source: https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model

Answer (score 2):

The `model.save()` will save many details about your NN. Most important details are

1. The architectures of the network including the dimensions (inputs/outputs layers, hidden layers ...etc).
2. The weights matrices for every hidden unit in each layer and the activation function. 
   and many other details that we may not need to outline here.

Coming back to the second part of your question, when we save the trained model, it will be saved the loss value after the last epoch. Which mean, the final value will be less or more from the previous epochs depending on the number of epochs you specified and how close you get from `overfitting`.

Also, the number of epochs is not saved and it doesn't make sense in most situations according to Francois Chollet the creator of `Keras`. [see this conversation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1766)

This is true unless you activate the `callback` option that turns on the early stopping of the training of your network after a certain number of epochs (which you called the best iteration). see [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1766)

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, what does model.save() saves , "Is it save the weights
>   it got from lat epoch(i.e., 100)" OR "Is it saves the weights from
>   best epoch (i,e., epoch 85)" OR "Average or mean weights from all 100
>   epochs"?.

What all things  are saved(weights, optimizer state etc.) are already mentioned in the other answers. In your case, the weights of the model at the end of 100 epochs are saved.

In case, you would like to save the best model(with the least loss), then you need to create a `ModelCheckPoint` callback object and pass it to the `fit()` method via the `callbacks` argument.

https://keras.io/callbacks/#ModelCheckpoint

https://keras.io/callbacks/#example-model-checkpoints